# Parsing multiple files for HTML tables and appending to single file in R

Tags: html, parsing, r, loops

This is a small project in R that I am attempting to execute. I've scraped a few hundred html pages. I am able to use the reaHTMLTable function in the XML library with R to read the tables that I'm interested in. However I'm having trouble writing the for loop to loop through the directory, grab the table from each file and append them to a single CSV file.

I HAVE been successful in looping through the files and saving each table to a single txt file (which I feel is at least a start):

```
library(XML)     # htmlTreeParse
  parentpath <- "Z:/scraping"
  setwd(parentpath)
  filenames <- list.files()
      for (targetfile in filenames){
      setwd(parentpath)
      data = readHTMLTable(targetfile)
      outputfile <- paste(targetfile,'.txt', sep="")
write.table (data[6], file = outputfile , sep = "\t", quote=TRUE)
```

Comment: have you tried `append = TRUE` with a single file name?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the append=TRUE option in write.table do the trick for you? You can read about it by looking up ?write.table.

Comment: Yep...you're right. append=TRUE does the trick. I believe I had tried that earlier too however I had been forgetting my trailing close bracket } at the end of my code and nothing was getting returned. Thanks!